# Tikz: define label font size under the node

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I create a picture of array which consists of nodes. I wonder how I can set the font size for the label which is below every cell (for example make it as `scriptsize`).
This are my definitions:

```
\def\cells#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{
  \foreach [count=\i from 0] \j  in {1,...,#1} {
    \node[cell,label=below:\i] (cell\i) at (\i*0.5,0) {};
  }
}

\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {draw, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, minium size = 0.5cm}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does your `\cells` command take seven arguments when you only use one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add `\scriptsize`:

```
\node[cell,label=below:{\scriptsize \i}]
```

You can change the font or whatever in the same way.

Comment: I didn't expected it will be so easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I know it's more tedious for this simple example, but for educational purposes it might be interesting to see how to add proper TikZ styles to the label:

```
\node[cell,label={[font=\small, red, rotate=20]below:\i}]
```

Note that the braces around the value in `label={[]stuff}` are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pstricks}
\psset{dimen = m}

\begin{document}

\def\cells{11} % number of cells
\begin{pspicture}(\cells,1.4)
  \multido{\r = 0.5+1, \i = 0+1}{\cells}{%
    \psframe(!\r\space 0.5 sub 0.4)(!\r\space 0.5 add 1.4)
    \rput(\r,0.9){$0$}
    \rput(\r,0.1){\scriptsize $\i$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I like to imagine the people posting "A PSTricks Solution" answers to TikZ questions to be brave warriors, vigorously fighting their last stand against the horde of TiKZ questions flooding the realms of TeX.SX. I know it's silly, but your Viking avatar just fits perfectly into this scenario. `:-D` +1

Answer (score 1):

Just 4 fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](11,1.5)
    \foreach \i in {0,...,10}{\rput(\i,.5){\psframe(1,1)\rput(.5,.5){0}\uput[-90](.5,0){\i}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]