# Tikz: draw a circle only in selected nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, conditionals

I created a table of nodes using tikz. And now I want to draw a circle inside every even node. I started from just trying to draw a circle in the second node. But my code is not working:

```
\begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=1pt,auto]
        \hashcells{12}
        \foreach [count=\i from 0] \number in {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}{
          \node at (hashcell\i) {\number};
          \if \i==2
            \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (0.1cm) node (sun) {};
          \fi
          }
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

Whereas the code below works fine and draws a circle in the first node. So I suppose there is something wrong with my `if` statement:

```
 \begin{center}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=1pt,auto]
            \hashcells{12}
            \foreach [count=\i from 0] \number in {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}{
              \node at (hashcell\i) {\number};
               \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (0.1cm) node (sun) {};
              }
          \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{center}
```

If someone can suggest what I am doing wrong I will be grateful.

Comment: Could you please provide a compilable MWE?

Comment: `\ifnum\i=2`? ..

Comment: Try `\ifodd\i\else...\fi` or `\ifnum\i=2...\fi`.

Comment: Where is `\hashcells` from? It is not in the TiKZ manual.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it's my own defined cell, but I am pretty sure that this definition is not needed. The problem was very easy and Adrew's answer helped me to solve it.

Comment: @Ziva The point is that you should post an example which people can compile. If the definition is not needed, that's fine - leave it out of the code you post in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previous note: Please, next time provide a COMPLETE minimal working (or not) example: starting from `\documentclass...` and finishing with `\end{document}` with all libraries and personal functions you use to test your code.

Answer: I'm not sure about what you want to do but if you just want to add some `filled circles` to previous defined nodes you can do it outside the `foreach` loop. Node names are known after `foreach` so you can make reference to them. There's no need for `if` inside the loop to add color to a particular node. If you don't know the particular name or want to `calculate` it forget my answer.

If you draw a filled circle at a node center you'll cover its contents, but you can use `backgrounds` library to add the filled circle behind the node. Both examples are shown in next code.

Final note: I've suposed that `\hashcell` was related to your previous question [Tikz: define label font size under the node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200901/tikz-define-label-font-size-under-the-node)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {draw, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, minimum size = 0.5cm}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach [count=\i from 0] \j  in {1,...,7} {
    \node[cell,label=below:{\scriptsize \i}] (cell\i) at (\i*0.5,0) {};}

\foreach [count=\i from 0] \number in {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}{
              \node at (cell\i) {\number};
              }

               \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (0.2cm) node (sun) {};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
              \draw [fill=yellow] (cell2.center) circle (0.2cm) node (sun) {};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think an easy approach is to use a `matrix of nodes` to draw the initial table. This automatically asigns a name to each cell, in the form `matrix_name-Row-Column` so it is easy to later add the circle via a loop.

```
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {inner sep=2pt, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em, draw}
}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, every node/.append style=cell] (M) {
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
};

\foreach \cell in {2,4,6}
  \draw[fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.4] (M-1-\cell) circle(.8em);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Here another approach using the `pic`-environment (available since pgf 3.0). I got two code examples using even/odd or custom positions for the yellow circles. This way the elements are predefined and can easily be reused in the `\foreach` statement.

The code should be self-explanatory, in doubt just ask.

**Info:** The both examples just differ in the `\foreach`-loop and a `\usepackage{xifthen}`. Style definitions are all the same. I just put it in two separate examples for a better understanding.

> Even/Odd-Approach

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\mysize}{.5cm}
  \tikzset{
   base/.style={minimum size=\mysize, draw, rectangle, label={below:{\scriptsize \x}}},
   cell/.pic={ %
    \node [base] at (0,0) {\lbl};
   },
   sun/.pic={ %
    \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (.2cm);
    \pic at (0,0) {cell};
   },
  }

  \foreach \x\lbl [count=\i] in {1/,2/0,3/1,4/0,5/1,6/0,7/0} {
   \newcommand{\mypos}{\x*\mysize, 0}
   \ifodd\i % if you need even, just swap the pic-commands
    \pic at (\mypos) {sun};
   \else
    \pic at (\mypos) {cell};
   \fi
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

> Custom position approach (needs package `xifthen`)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\mysize}{.5cm}
  \tikzset{
   base/.style={minimum size=\mysize, draw, rectangle, label={below:{\scriptsize \x}}},
   cell/.pic={ %
    \node [base] at (0,0) {\lbl};
   },
   sun/.pic={ %
    \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (.2cm);
    \pic at (0,0) {cell};
   },
  }

  \foreach \x\lbl [count=\i] in {1/,2/0,3/1,4/0,5/1,6/0,7/0} {
   \newcommand{\mypos}{\x*\mysize,0}
   \ifthenelse { %
    \i=1 \OR \i=3 \OR \i=6 % here go your x-positions
   } { %
    \pic at (\mypos) {sun};
   } { %
    \pic at (\mypos) {cell};
   }
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]